A question about how to use Ito's lemma
I am just a beginner for stochastic process and I encountered a question like
"Suppose $\dfrac{dY}{Y}=\bigg(
\beta_t+\dfrac{1}{2}t^2    
\bigg)dt+td\beta$ is the stochastic process for $Y$ where $\beta_t=\displaystyle 
\int_0^\beta d\beta$ is a
random walk based on the Brownian motion process $d\beta$. What is $Y_t$ as a function of
$t$ and $\beta_t$?"
My idea is: Let $y$ be an Ito process given by
$$
dy = \beta_t dt + t d\beta
$$
and define a function $f(t,y)=\mathrm{e}^y$. Then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0,\quad 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\mathrm{e}^y,\quad 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=\mathrm{e}^y,\quad 
$$
By Ito's Lemma,
\begin{align*}
    df(t,y)& =
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt +  
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy +  
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}t^2 dt \\
    &=\mathrm{e}^y(\beta_tdt+t d\beta)+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^y t^2 dt\\ 
    &=\mathrm{e}^y\bigg( \beta_t+\frac{1}{2}t^2 \bigg)dt+\mathrm{e}^yt d\beta
\end{align*}
That is
$$
\frac{df}{f}=\bigg( \beta_t+\frac{1}{2}t^2 \bigg)dt+t d\beta
$$
And I do not know how to continue to find $y_t$. Moreover, I cannot see whether it is proper to set $dy=\beta_tdt+td_\beta$. Can anyone help?

You can do a separation of variables + Ito integration by parts. Integrating both sides of the equation,
$$
\int_0^T\frac{d Y}{Y}=\int_0^T\left(B_t+\frac{1}{2} t^2\right) d t+\int_0^Tt d B_t.
$$
Using Ito integration by parts,
$$TB_T = \int_0^TB_tdt + \int_0^TtdB_t$$
which we can plug in to obtain
$$\log(Y_T)-\log(Y_0)=\frac{T^3}{6}+TB_T $$
yielding
$$Y_T = Y_0e^{\frac{T^3}{6}+TB_T}.$$

In the penultimate equation, $t$ should be $T$.

@GiuseppeNegro Fixed thanks!
